# Preview image in OpenDialog

Tags: vb.net, image, preview, fileopendialog

In Visual Basic.NET, when browsing to a file via the OpenFileDialog control, is it possible to display a preview of an image when an image is selected in the OpenDialog?

Answer (score 0):

The OpenFileDialog is a high level built in Dialog. The previw impage option doesn't exist.
If you want it, you must develope another DialogBox.